# How is called a "hierarchy" without singletons? How to represent it correctly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A hierarchy $H$ on $E$ is defined by 3 properties:

1. $E$ belongs to $H$
2. if $X$ and $Y$ both belong to $H$ then either they are disjoint or one is included in the other one (i.e. their intersection equals the empty space, $X$ or $Y$).
3. if $s$ belongs to $E$, then the singleton $\{s\}$ belongs to $H$

How would one call a structure that matches the first two properties but not the third (i.e. some singletons may be missing)?

Also, a dendrogram does not seem to correspond well to such a structure because the union of all leaves would not equal to whole set $E$. What representation should I use?

Comment: Were the tags chosen by rolling a D12 die?

Comment: Why? This doesn't help... Please do you have an answer?

Comment: The question is, why do you want to talk about structures that satisfy this property? Would you care to construct one?

Comment: How you represent this structure will probably depend on what you're using it for.

Comment: An example of such structure: family of ultrametric balls in ultrametric space.